Calculating sequence of TD($\lambda$) returns
I am having some trouble with answering the following question:
A rat is involved in an experiment. It experiences one episode. At the first step it hears a bell. At the second step it sees a light. At the third step it both hears a bell and sees a light. It then receives some food, worth +1 reward, and the episode terminates on the fourth step. All other rewards were zero. The experiment is undiscounted.
Approximate the state-value function by a linear combination of these features with two parameters: $b · bell(s) + l · light(s)$. If $b = 2$ and $l = −2$, write down the sequence of $\lambda$-returns $v_t^\lambda$ corresponding to this episode, for $\lambda = 0.5$.
The provided answer is this:
$v^\lambda_1 = 0.5 (−2 + 0.5×0 + 0.5×1) = −3/4$
$v^\lambda_2 = 0.5 (0 + 1×1) = 1/2$
$v^\lambda_3 = 0.5 (2×1) = 1$
However, these are my calculations:
$v^\lambda_1 = 0.5 (.5^0×−2 + .5^1×0 + .5^2×1) = 0.875$
$v^\lambda_2 = 0.5 (.5^0×0 + .5^1×1) = 1/4$
$v^\lambda_3 = 0.5 (.5^0×1) = 1/2$
Any help is appreciated!
